# Abrir arquivo .pas pelo explorer no win10

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ide

Utilizo o Delphi 7 e após fazer a troca do windows 7 para o windows 10 (Enterprise), não estou conseguindo mais abrir arquivos do tipo **.pas** diretamente do Explorer.

Quando utilizo o duplo click no arquivo **.pas** é aberta uma nova instância do Delphi, porém sem trazer o arquivo desejado.

Já tentei abrir o arquivo executando como administrador, porém sem sucesso.

Sempre que necessário abrir um arquivo **.pas** preciso abrir o mesmo utilizando o OpenDialogs do próprio Delphi.

Alguém já passou por essa situação?

Comment: Você precisa colocar como Programa padrão o Delphi para abri .pas

Answer (score 0):

Mudar os programas padrão no Windows 10

1. No menu **Iniciar** , selecione ***Configurações*** .
2. Selecione ***Aplicativos*** > ***Aplicativos padrão.***
3. Role a página até o fim e clique em “***Definir padrões por aplicativo***”
4. Selecione o aplicativo padrão que você deseja definir no caso o (*Delphi*)  e, em seguida, escolha as ***Extenções*** .

Ps: Os aplicativos precisam estar instalados para que você possa defini-los como o padrão.

Comment: Seguindo os passos, não encontrei o Delphi na lista dos padrões por aplicativos. Ele já esta instalado a um tempo neste computador. Verificando em outro computador com Windows 10 e Delphi o mesmo não aparece também nesta lista.

Comment: você terá que adicionar deve ter lá uma opção de adicionar programa aos programas padrão. (Não estou com o win 10 aberto aqui para ver). Mais 100% de certeza que é assim para add programa padrão no win 10